# Plugin ubuntu Desktop

Tags: application-development, desktop-environments, plugins, development

I'm want to do a plugin to Ubuntu in my term paper, but i never had seen something like this to ubuntu.

I want to know about the complexity to "extend" an OS, how much time will spend to do something like this?
What languages could I use?
What kind of biography I must to read?

Sorry if i haven't followed some asking pattern, but i'm hurry about this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question is too broad and unclear. What are exactly trying to do? What 'parts' are you trying to 'extend'? For example: do you want to enhance the email client? Do you want to speed up startup? Do you want to develop a brand new calendar application?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways you can 'plug in' to the Ubuntu Desktop. You could develop a [scope](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/tutorials/scopes/writing-a-unity-scope/) for searching in the dash. You can [develop an indicator](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/application-indicators/) or integrate with the [messaging](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/messaging-menu/) or [sound](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/sound-menu/) menu.

There are many more ways to extend the OS - it is, after all, open source and you can modify any part of it. The ways I've mentioned are probably the easiest and best documented way though.

Comment: I've read your answer links, and this looks like very complicated to do in a term paper, do you know some way to create something like this using Java, maybe Python, and develop in a high level?